# QGIS Least cost additional constraints

Tags: qgis, cost-path, geology

I am looking to create a least cost path for a pipe line based on a landslide risk map. I was wondering if a least cost analysis has the possibility to put additional constraints on the pathing i.e 90° turns cost more. with the goal that the path it takes is mostly straight where possible?